# Pandas insert column with massive data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 54 CSV files each of them having 3 million rows.

I want to add a new column for each of the CSV file.

So I implemented as follows:

```
local_list = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ORI_LOCAL_NAME","DES_LOCAL_NAME"])

for i in range(0,df.__len__()):
    row = df.iloc[i,:]
    ori_name = row['ORI_TOLL_NAME']
    des_name = row['DES_TOLL_NAME']
    ori_local_name = toll_info[ori_name]
    des_local_name = toll_info[des_name]
    local_list = local_list.append({"ORI_LOCAL_NAME": ori_local_name, 
                                    "DES_LOCAL_NAME": des_local_name},
                          ignore_index=True)


df:
            DATE   ORI_TOLL_NAME DES_TOLL_NAME  
0        20130201              a            a   
1        20130201              a            b   
2        20130201              a            c   
3        20130201              a            d  

desired df via conneting local_list:
            DATE   ORI_TOLL_NAME DES_TOLL_NAME ORI_LOCAL_NAME DES_LOCAL_NAME   
0        20130201              a            a               A              A
1        20130201              a            b               A              A 
2        20130201              a            c               A              B
3        20130201              a            d               A              C
```

I make a `local_list` dataframe to insert new column following `df`.

The `df` is single dataFrame which the have 3m row.

`ori_local_name` and `des_local_name` newly are defined data which find from free defined dictionary `toll_info`. `ori_local_name` and `des_local_name` could be duplicative along the each rows.

But before concating `local_list` and `df`, it is too slow handling 3m rows...

Is there any way to improve speed for inserting column?

Comment: You are not supposed to call functions whose names begin with a double underscore (like `df.__len__()`). Instead, use `len(df)` or, better, `df.shape[0]`.

Comment: You seem to be appending rows, and not using vectorization. Appending to a dataframe (`local_list`) is an expensive operation. Try to append complete dataframes instead of rows.

Comment: @ritchie46 could you explain more detail please? I want to add (column-wise) local_list into df

Comment: If you can give me some more details on how your data is looking. Or give a small example with fake data.

Answer (score 1):

Stop looping.  Simply create the new column at once using [`Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['ORI_LOCAL_NAME'] = df['ORI_TOLL_NAME'].map(toll_info)
```

Comment: What a silly question myself... I solve the problems but still want to figure out effectively adding a row in pandas